# Python Django video stream control duration

Tags: python, django

I start to develop small video tube using Django.

I have full time video, e.g. 30min., for member zone.

I would like to show only 3min (e.g. from 3rd to 6th min) chunk from this video in public zone for non-reg users.

I can cut video and have two copies on HDD: full time and 3min chunk.

But I'm interested to have one full time video and limit duration on fly on code level (server side).

I can't find libs doing something like this.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: @LazerBass Thanks! I can't send example, because I can't find the way to start from. I'm reading Django docs, but I can't find idea.